# How to expand a list based on a predefined increment?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
list1[0,4]
```

I want to expand the list 3-fold and add 10 to each element during each expansion. My result should look like this:

```
list2[0,4,10,14,20,24]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list2=list1
for i in range(2):
    list1=list1+[j+10*(i+1) for j in list2]
print list1
```